# How do I insert a UniqueID into multiple rows in SQL with Coldfusion?

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I've created a new table `(subscribers)` and am pulling the email address
from another table `(MailingList)`. I'm also inserting a flag `Sub` and a `UserID`.

The `Sub` flags whether the user is active or not, while the `UserID` will be used in
a URL to identify the user who chooses to unsubscribe.

My problem is when running the query, the `#createUUID()#` is the **same** in every record.

How can I create **UNIQUE** IDs?

```
<cfquery name="LoadSubs"  datasource="#dsn#">
    INSERT INTO subscribers (email, Sub, UserID)
    SELECT 
        email, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value='1'>, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#createUUID()#'>
    FROM MailingList;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the mysql inbuilt function uuid() instead of the cfml `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value='#createUUID()#'>` variation?

Comment: OK... so I inserted `NewID()` as  `uniqueindetifier` and then converted `uniqueindetifier` to `varchar(300)` and it worked. Not sure if it's the best approach, but the result is what I needed. Thanks for your help. It sent me down the right road. :)

Comment: `the #createUUID()# is the same in every record` That's because it's a CF function. When  a cfquery is executed, the CF server first evaluates any cfml #variables#. Then plugs those generated values into the SQL string before sending it to your db for execution. That means the createUUID() function is only ever executed once,

Comment: Based only on what's in this question, consider dropping the subscribers table and adding the `sub` field to the MailingList table.

Comment: Are you bulk inserting the records?  How is your query executed on the page?

If you execute the query block only once (one insert) per request, It shouldn't have the unique ids duplicated.

Comment: @akashb - Yes, it should (and will) duplicate the uuid.  createUUID() isn't a database function, and it isn't executed once per row.  The function is executed *once* in CF before the query is handed off to the db. That's it.  It only ever generates *one* value. Bottom line, it's what the code is supposed to do. Whether it's what people "expect" to happen is a different story....

Answer (score 1):

OK... so I inserted `NewID()` as `uniqueindetifier` and then converted `uniqueindetifier` to `varchar(300)` and it worked. Not sure if it's the best approach, but the result is what I needed.

Comment: It puts a heavier load on SQL Server than ColdFusion. That is typically a good thing. You may also want to consider `NewID()` to be the default value for your table. That way it is just always there.

Comment: Why change uniqueidentifier to varchar (... and size 300)? Uniqueidentifier should work with NewID. Also the docs say the length of [uniqueidentifier is 36](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks much for the input. Essentially I'm re-creating the table from another site that was previously built by another coder who was hired to build it there. I will certainly look at going back to the  `uniqueidentifier` or drop the length of the `varchar` down.